# How to send text message via android app to an actual cell phone (not built in android phone)

Tags: android

I have built an application that sends a text message using the phone number and a default message like the following:

```
 private void sendMessage(String number, String message){
        try{
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(number,null,message,null,null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and where the function is called is the following:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendMessage("9000001", "Hello there");
            openAvctivity3();
        }
    });
```

(note that the 9000001 is not my actual phone number it is just put as a sample cell phone)

The app runs with no problems and if you go to the text message app on the built in sample android phone the messages appear as sent. However, it is not received at my actual cell phone and I was unsure as to how to do that. I wanted to know if there was a way to send a text message directly to my cell phone (in person not virtual/built in). Thanks.